# How to select an answer to a question that I recently asked?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, up-votes, voting

In my most recent question regarding whether to abandon an open math problem, I got (surprisingly) much more dialogue than I anticipated.  I had expected very quick answers that all say something like, "yes, you are mistaken, stick with what's current."

Instead, I got some great answers that advocate for both choices.

There is a concise answer that has 46 up-votes -- the most net up-votes.

Then Pete Clark's answer has 26 net up-votes and Dan Romik has 9 net up-votes.

I think Pete Clark's and Dan Romik's answers (and additional comments) are the best.

Am I doing something "wrong" if I choose one of their answers, instead of choosing the answer that is the most popular, based on up-votes?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers):

> As the author of the question, you have an additional option:
>   accepting an answer that you believe is the best solution to your
>   problem.
>
> To accept an answer:
>
> - Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your
>     problem.
> - To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside
>     the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
> - You may change
>     which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.
>
> Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept
>   the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that
>   answers your question well.

Note the repeated reference to the "answer that **you believe** is the best". Choose any answer you want (or none at all).

Comment: Ok, thanks @ff524 :)

Comment: In addition to the above comments, it may be helpful to edit your original question to provide insight into why the correct answers were chosen for your particular topic.